# For each element in the list

Tags: prolog

I'm new in prolog, I have a problem.

I got a list of numbers like [7,88,10,11] and what I want to do is:

```
for each element in [7,88,10,11] A

       for each element in [88,10,11] B
                for each element in [10,11] C
                       write(A-B-C).
```

I want all the combinations (permutations of 3 elements) in the list.

Thank you!

**Edit:** The list is an example, the actual list is L:

```
list(L,J) :- findall(X,(task(X,K),K==J),L).
```

So then I would like to iterate like I said through list L.

Comment: So do you want len(list) P 3 (speaking combinatorically) or will B and C remain `[88,10,11] and [10,11]` respectively

Comment: I mean like a for that iterates over all the elements,B and C have to remain the same because then you have to do it with the next element of A,all the possible combinations.
BTW A,B and C are the index of the for,it's an example.

Comment: When A progresses from `7` to `88`, does B shrink from `[88,10,11]` to `[10,11]` or does it become `[7,10,11]`

Comment: B stays the same,because now you have to do all the combination that starts with 88:
88-88-10, 88-88-11,88-10-10,88-10-11,88-11-10,88-11-11
And then A is 10 and the samen and then with 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actual prolog code is very similar to your description

```
?- forall((member(A, [7,88,10,11]),
           member(B, [88,10,11]),
           member(C, [10,11])
          ), writeln(A-B-C)).
```

you can think of comma operator as join in SQL (in the simple syntax select * from A,B,C)

*edit*: of course, that code is *not* similar at all to your description. Should be instead

```
?- forall(member(A, [7,88,10,11]),
          forall(member(B, [88,10,11]),
                 forall(member(C, [10,11]), writeln(A-B-C)))).
```

(hope I balanced right brackets...)

*edit*: sorry, I completely missed that relation among A,B,C. Does

```
?- L = [7,88,10,11],
   forall((select(A,L,L1),
           select(B,L1,L2),
           member(C,L2)
          ), writeln(A-B-C)).
```

works better ?

Comment: Well the thing is that I don't know the elements of the list,they are in a variable L so i cannot do this...

Comment: Thank you very much! But now I have a problem:
1 2 3 4, 
1 2 3 5, 
1 2 3 6, 
1 2 4 3 <-- this last number should be 5 as it is later than 4 in the list.Also this combination is the same as the first one.

Comment: Finally did it! Thank you very much:
forall((select(A,L,L1),select(B,L1,L2),select(C,L2,L3),member(D,L3),B > A,C > B,D > C),writeln(A-B-C-D)).